# Photos.framework throws <Error>: ImageIO: PNG zlib error but still provides UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, uiimage, photosframework

I found a similar question here:
[iOS 8 (Swift) How do I get rid of this error: ImageIO: PNG zlib error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117605/ios-8-swift-how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-error-imageio-png-zlib-error) however there are some differences.

I get the `PHAsset` from a picker - where the image does download and display properly (It uses the `PHCachingImageManager` class).

But, when I try to request the image later from the Asset like so:

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:AssetTargetSize
    contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:nil 
    resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
        if (result)
            _image = result;
}
```

the `result` variable is a pointer to a `UIImage` object but is not valid - I cannot turn it into NSData nor can I quicklook through xcode.

In the log I just get the following message: `<Error>: ImageIO: PNG zlib error` and nothing more.

I tried to make the request synchronous as suggested in the linked question, but it made no difference.

The image pointed at by the `PHAsset` is viewable both in the Photos app and the photo picker.

Comment: "I tried to make the request synchronous as suggested..."

Can you provide your updated code, please?  It would also help to be able to see how you are setting AssetTargetSize...

Comment: @KickimusButticus Since it didn't work I restored my code back to what is written (I'd prefer asynchronous), however it was done by creating the options class and only changing the synchronous property to `YES`. `AssetTargetSize` is a static const of type `CGSize` which is hardcoded for now. This code works most of the time, however I get this error without any extra information for some images - but since the image is loaded in the image picker - I doubt this is a problem with my images

Comment: all of my square image taking by Camera.app get the same error

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @NateBirkholz unfortunately not.. I haven't tested it on the newest SDK though, it's possible it has been fixed. Although if this thread is still getting hits I doubt it..

Comment: @AlexanderNorth I solved it by doing the synchronous option *and* also not resizing the image to a square aspect ratio. Both were required. Sounds like an SDK bug for sure.

Comment: @NateBirkholz can you share code as answer here? that will help full to others

Comment: @karthikeyan It turned out that I just had to create the size externally to the call to requestImageForAsset. I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

We need to enable synchronous  option.

```
PHAsset *asset = array[i];
            PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
             options.synchronous  = YES;
            PHImageManager *imageManager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
            [imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:CGSizeMake(200, 200) contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
                badge = (UIImage *)result;
            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by setting the aforementioned synchronous options to true as well as setting the size externally to the call to requestImageForAsset. *Both* were required, for me, for it to work. In Swift 2.*x*:

```
    let aSize = CGFloat(200) // it's really a constant elsewhere in the project
    let targetSize = CGSizeMake(aSize, aSize)
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    options.synchronous = true

    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: { (image, info) -> Void in
        guard let imageFor = image else { return }
        // use (now-unwrapped) imageFor here
    })
```